# Android Generated with 0 build variant

Tags: android, react-native, build

When i try to generate a signed apk it says "generated a signed apk with 0 build variants" and the apk is broken, it crashes when i try to open it after installing.

It works fine in development mode and debug.
I need this to ONLY work in release

Answer (score 0):

I updated top level Gradle from
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
to
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1"